# GET localhost URL through HTTParty in localhost server, produces Net::ReadTimeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, httparty

I am testing a scenario and getting this error:

`Net::ReadTimeout in controller#method-one`. I tried three ways

**Console: (works fine):**

```
HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/controller/method-two?prams=abc")
```

**Single Server running on localhost:3000: (shows error):**

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
   require 'net/http'
   def method-one
    abc = params[:abc]
    res=HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/controller/method-two?prams=#{abc}")
   end
end
```

**Two Server running on different ports localhost:3001/0: (shows error):**

both server call each other controller#method just to change port i.e

**Server on Port 3000 call:**

```
HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3001/controller/method-other-server?prams=#{abc}")
```

above Get call the server on port 3001 controller#method-other-server which again call back origin server another method to record response i.e.

```
HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/controller/method-two?prams=#{abc}")
```

and origin server running on port 3000 get stuck for while and produces 
Net::ReadTimeout error on origin server port 3000

you might be wonder why I am using two server for one call. because I read over internet that:

> Localhost server is single threaded so you can't call a localhost url inside the localhost server.

please help me I am stuck being beginner in rails.

P.S: I've tested these method independently and works fine. but problem rise when I call url from one controller method to another method through `HTTParty`

Comment: Goal is: method-one should call method-two through HTTParty in same localhost server same controller.

Comment: Why do you need to call another method via HTTP request? Is it an option to call the other method directly within the same server instance? How does the other method look like?

Comment: Its a test case. and method-two only populate database.